# django-admin and static files

Tags: django

I'm new to django and recently I'm following [this tutorial](http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list2.html#interactive-toggle-boxes) 
to write a todo-list app.
In part 2 I should customize the admin's change_list template and add an image into it.
At first I use

```
<img class='btn' src='static/img/on.png'>
```

but it turns out to be invalid.
Can anybody figure out what's the problem is? Thanks a lot.

Here is my folder structure

```
todo-list
   todo-app
        img
          ----on.png
          ----off.png
   templates
        admin
           ----change_list.html
   todo-list
```

Comment: And where's the `static` folder?

Comment: the default STATIC_URL variable is '/static/'

Comment: Right, but if you don't have a `static` folder in your app folder, then how do you expect it work?

Comment: as @Lev Levitsky said, you need to add static folder under `todo-app` app in that you need to place `img` folder

Answer (score 1):

you can't access the static file( images, css, js ) directly in django

to serve the static files you need to use `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` or `{{STATIC_URL}}` for that [How do I include image files in Django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901551/how-do-i-include-image-files-in-django-templates), and [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

this will helps u :)

Comment: I think it's `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in newer versions.

Comment: am used this in 1.4 version also

Comment: I've already add `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` in the urls.py,and I can access the image using `<img class='btn' src='static/img/on.png'>` in normal templates, but I can't do this in admin template,so I think it's a problem with admin?