# Cannot load image in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to django. I tried to load an image through HTML(graph.html).
views.py includes

```
def avg_duration_vs_time_of_day(request):
    figName="figGraph.png"
    path="Telecom/Images/"+figName
    day = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    query = "select time_of_day,avg(duration) from fact_table group by time_of_day"
    avg_call_day = connect(query)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.figure(figsize = (4,4))
    plt.xlabel("Time of Day",fontdict={'fontsize':8})
    plt.ylabel("Average Call Duration in seconds",fontdict={'fontsize':8}) 
    plt.title("Average Call Versus Time of Day",fontdict = {'fontsize':8})
    plt.plot(day,avg_call_day,color='green', linestyle='solid',linewidth=1, marker='o',markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=0)
    plt.bar(day,avg_call_day,width=0.2,align='center')
    plt.savefig(path)
    image_data = open(path, "rb").read()
    context = { 'image_data': image_data }    
    return render_to_response('welcome/graph.html', context)
```

graph.html includes

```
<div>
<img src="{% 'views.avg_duration_vs_time_of_day.image_data' %} " />
</div>
```

But image cannot load in the browser and the error is

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /graph/
Invalid block tag: ''views.avg_duration_vs_time_of_day.image_data''
```

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You should put image path in a template context, instead of image itself:

```
context = { 'image_path': path }    
return render_to_response('welcome/graph.html', context)
```

And, your template syntax is incorrect:

```
<div>
<img src="{{ image_path }}"/>
</div>
```

Hope your settings are configured properly. FYI, see:

- [How do I include image files in Django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901551/how-do-i-include-image-files-in-django-templates)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have changed my settings.py as   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'Images/media')       MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/admin/' but it is not working properly I have saved that image in Images directory inside my project folder

Comment: Then, save your image inside `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: I changed MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'Images') but still not working

Comment: Try as `MEDIA_ROOT = '/path_on_you_server/images/'` and `MEDIA_URL = '/images/'`. After you must save your images into the folder `'/path_on_you_server/images/'`

Comment: I am also facing similar problem. I could not comprehend what path_on_you_server means.