# Image does not appear Django template

Tags: python, html, django, image, django-templates

I am trying to load some images into a template but it continues to appear as broken link
My files and directories are as follows
1.views.py

```
def home(request):
    #template = loader.get_template("polls/home.html")
    return render_to_response('polls/home.html',
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

2.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^applications/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^', include('polls.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

3.home.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>psdtowebSimpleWebsiteTemplate.psd</title>
        <link href="{% static 'C:\Users\omars_000\Desktop\mytask\polls\templates\polls\styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background">
            <div id="background"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/Capture.png"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

4.settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)
```

Any idea why it is not working? I have checked many questions but nothing helped so far.

Comment: If you try to access the URL generated by `<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/Capture.png">` , do you get a valid URL ?

Comment: @karthikr yes it's a valid url and the image appears in the browser but in case of template, it appears broken link

Comment: Ok.. check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1235542/1628832 ( your URL pattern)

Comment: @karthikr already checked it and still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MEDIA_URL` already has a trailing slash.  You are adding another in `<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/Capture.png">`  Most browsers don't care, but perhaps yours does.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
In home.html I fixed to be as follows:

```
<div id="background"><img src="{% static "C:\Users\omars_000\Desktop\mytask\mytask\media\images\background.png" %}""></div>
```

and in settings.py I added the location of the images i will be using in the template as follows:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:\Users\omars_000\Desktop\mytask\mytask\media\images',
    'C:\Users\omars_000\Desktop\mytask\mytask\media',
)
```