# MEDIA_ROOT not appended to the ImageField url

Tags: python, django

The model is defined as follow:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def upload_path(self, filename):
        return "product_images/" + self.title.lower().replace(" ", "_") + path.splitext(filename)[1]
    img_sum = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
```

The view is simply:

```
class HomeView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'products_list'
    template_name = 'core/home.html'
    model = Product
```

And the template tries to display an image :

```
        {% for p in products_list %}
        <a href="#">
            <article class="product_frame">
                <img src="{{ p.img_sum.url }}" />
                <h3>{{ p.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ p.summary }}</p>
            </article>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
```

The MEDIA_ROOT is explicitly set to

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/me/workspace/website/www/core/media/'
```

However, it looks like `MEDIA_ROOT` is never appended to the path defined in the model. As a sanity check, here is what I get from the shell for a test `Product` instance provided through the django admin interface:

```
In [20]: p = Product.objects.all()[3]

In [21]: p
Out[21]: <Product: Title : Test -- This is a test>

In [22]: p.img_sum
Out[22]: <ImageFieldFile: product_images/test.jpg>

In [23]: p.img_sum.url
Out[23]: '/media/product_images/test.jpg'
```

So when I call `{{ p.img_sum.url }}` in the template which is located under `www/core/templates`, it won't find the image file because the relative url should be `../media/product_images/test.jpg` instead of `/media/product_images/test.jpg`.

How can I resolve the good url for my image files ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the `MEDIA_URL` in settings.py to `'../media/'`.

Comment: What should be its value in this specific case ? I tried '/media/' but it did not work out.

Comment: Thanks. Now it does not seem to be a problem of relative path. In my template I manually added this :

`<img src="/media/product_images/test.jpg" />
<img src="/static/core/img/envelope.png" />`

The first image won't show but the second one will, though both files are definitely present. I really don't get it.

Comment: So to be clear : the path should be relative to the location of the `views.py`, and in that case the '/media/' is correct for MEDIA_URL (actually I don't even need it). The problem is just that images won't get displayed if they are stored under /media, and they will if they are under /static.

Comment: When debug = True the behavior of static (media) serving is slighty different.  
[Try out those docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was not related to file location but rather to the fact that Django does not serve media files by default in the dev environment. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901551/how-do-i-include-image-files-in-django-templates) question helped to figure it out.