# How to embed images on a site django with dropbox?

Tags: django, heroku, dropbox

Deployed a blog on Heroku. I upload the picture to the record through the admin panel on Dropbox via django-storages. The picture appears in the Dropbox application, but I don’t understand how to load the link to it. How to embed Dropbox pictures? You can advise other ways. While the idea is only to manually link links to the database ...

Comment: Why not keep the images server side? Have you tried anything yet? Refer to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901551/how-do-i-include-image-files-in-django-templates)

Comment: Heroku have Ephemeral file system...